# css @keyframes animation not working in Safari for Windows

Tags: windows, css, safari, css-animations

I made a carousel script that can either fade, slide or do both as a transition. This can be set by changing the class name of the parent container (#moduleCarousel_12).

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jx8ufwg/11/ ]

In Chrome this works fine.

In Safari (for Win) however:

1. the fade only works if the parent also has "slide left" in the class name. Which is strange, since it only adds a second animation (left-positioning).

   ```css
   .moduleCarousel.fade > div.active {
       z-index: 3;
       opacity: 1;
       -webkit-animation-name: fade;
       animation-name: fade;
   }
   .moduleCarousel.slide.left.fade > div.active {
       -webkit-animation-name: slide-left, fade;
       animation-name: slide-left, fade;
   }

   /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   @-webkit-keyframes fade {
       0% {opacity: 0; -moz-opacity: 0;}
       100% {opacity: 1; -moz-opacity: 1;}
   }
   /* Standard syntax */
   @keyframes fade {
       0% {opacity: 0; -moz-opacity: 0;}
       100% {opacity: 1; -moz-opacity: 1;}
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes slide-left {
       0% {left: 100%;}
       100% {left: 0%;}
   }
   @keyframes slide-left {
       0% {left: 100%;}
       100% {left: 0%;}
   }
   ```

   2. the slide transition doesn't work at all

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Apple dropped support for Safari on Windows - don't bother making it work, since it's bugged and will not be updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari on windows isn't a "real" browser, It's emulated to kind of, work on it. There are a lot of bugs concerning it, and a lot of web designers have issues with it, and also Apple withdrew their support for safari on windows in 2012. The good part is that there's a higher chance of winning the lottery than finding a windows-safari-user.

Comment: As of Sept 2014, Safari 5.1 users make up 0.83% of internet users. I couldn't find a way to split Windows from Apple, but it's safe to assume that 100% of the 0.83% is not Windows. http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201309-201409

Answer (score 2):

So this is a bug in Safari (for Windows), for which there is no workaround apparently.

**EDIT:**
According to [CSS-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax) and [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) the way I defined the animations is correct. (Unless I'm missing something?) And it works in all browsers, except in Safari for Windows.

And since nobody knows why it doesn't work and, as Easwee and Gho have said,  there is no longer support from Apple for this version of the browser, the logical conclusion is: it's a bug and at this moment there is no fix. (And there probably never will be.)

But if I'm wrong or if I made a mistake in my script, please let me know.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The answer to the question is: there is no solution, it's a bug for which there is no fix. So, this IS in fact the right answer as Gho acknowledged. :) Unfortunately ofcourse :)

Comment: try editing your answer (annotate it as an 'edit', for clarity, usually done by using bold **EDIT**), instead of adding it as a comment ;)